# How to pass and read authorization bearer-token using python lambda function through api gateway?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a python lambda function that I want to decode and read the payload of a jwt.
I created a get method and passing the authorization bearer-token to the endpoint.
How can i pass and read the jwt using lambda function through api gateway?

Comment: Is the token passed in a header or in the get query parameters?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you've tried any code, then please post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the mapping template of method integration section. The mapping template utlises velocity template for creating the event. You can capture the headers and send them in the event.

Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

After invocation of lambda function, the JWT token can be captured in the event and you can retreive the payload.